# Mvvmcross: missing picture metadata

Tags: mvvmcross

**DESCRIPTION:** I'm uploading images to a server taken with a phone app using Mvvmcross TakePicture method.
**PROBLEM:** The original size image in the Gallery of the Phone contains the GPS tags, but the re-scaled one arriving to the server doesn't.

**INFO:** I've uploaded an image from a webpage to test the server side code an the GPS tag was there.

***This is the code where I'm taking the picture and saving it:***

```
_pictureChooserTask.TakePicture(MaxPixelDimension,DefaultJpegQuality,OnPicture,()=>{});
private void OnPicture(Stream stream)
{
    var memorystream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyToAsync(memorystream);
    PictureBytes = memorystream.ToArray();
    _fileStore.EnsureFolderExists("Images");
    var path = _fileStore.PathCombine("Images", "test.jpg");
    _fileStore.WriteFile(path, PictureBytes);
}
```

***This is the upload part:***

```
var result = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>().TryReadBinaryFile(imagePath, out imageBytes);
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.Count());                   
var fileName = mediaPartner.GpCode+Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
const string reference = "picture";
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    FileName = fileName,
    Name = reference,
};
content.Add(fileContent);
content.Add(new StringContent(Settings.UserId), "userid");
var backendresp = await client.PostAsync(server + route, content);
```

**QUESTION:** Is it possible that my image will lose the meta tags when it is re-scaled and saved or when it is prepared for upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MvvmCross plugin resizes using  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid/MvxPictureChooserTask.cs

This code won't preserve jpeg metadata - so if that's important to your app, then you'll need to write and inject your own implementation.